# Is there a way to extract all metadata from all types of file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract metadata from a bunch of files. The files can be image, video or just any type for that matter. I would like to extract all available metadata from the file regardless of the type. I tried using the `WindowsAPICodePack` and `Shell32`. I was able to extract a bunch of properties, but i needed 'Projection Type' metadata which was available in the file. But both `WindowsAPICodePack` and `Shell32` failed to extract the same. Any solutions?

Here is the `Shell 32` code i tried

```
List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();
List<Tuple<int, string, string>> attributes = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();

Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
var strFileName = @"C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\image.jpg";
Shell32.Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName));
Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = objFolder.ParseName(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName));


for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
{
    string header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        break;
    arrHeaders.Add(header);
}

// The attributes list below will contain a tuple with attribute index, name and value
// Once you know the index of the attribute you want to get, 
// you can get it directly without looping, like this:
var Authors = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 20);

for (int i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
{
    var attrName = arrHeaders[i];
    var attrValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, i);
    var attrIdx = i;

    attributes.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string>(attrIdx, attrName, attrValue));

    Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}: {2}", i, attrName, attrValue);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The code for `WindowsAPICodePack` is given below.

```
ShellObject file = ShellObject.FromParsingName(path);
            var props = file.Properties.DefaultPropertyCollection;
            var camera = file.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Photo.CameraModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some searching i ended up on using the [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

The tool is pretty efficient in extraction a lot of metadata, especially what i needed specifically - 'ProjectionType'. This property was used to check if the uploaded file is a 360 video/image. This is pretty much what i ended up with.

```
public List<Metadata> ExtractMetaDataExifTool(string filepath, string ExifToolPath)
    {
        #region ReadFromFile
        string output = "";
        var lstMetadata = new List<Metadata>();
        using (var p = new Process())
        {
            // exiftool command
            string toolPath = "";
            toolPath += " -s ";
            toolPath += "-fast -G -t -m -q -q -n ";
            toolPath += "\"" + filepath + "\"";

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "\"" + ExifToolPath + "\\exiftool.exe" + "\"";
            startInfo.Arguments = toolPath;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            bool status = p.Start();

            StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
            while (!p.HasExited)
            {
                q.Append(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            output = q.ToString();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        #endregion ReadFromFile

        #region ExtractFileMetadataFromString

        while (output.Length > 0)
        {
            int epos = output.IndexOf('\r');

            if (epos < 0)
                epos = output.Length;
            string tmp = output.Substring(0, epos);
            int tpos1 = tmp.IndexOf('\t');
            int tpos2 = tmp.IndexOf('\t', tpos1 + 1);

            if (tpos1 > 0 && tpos2 > 0)
            {
                string taggroup = tmp.Substring(0, tpos1);
                ++tpos1;
                string tagname = tmp.Substring(tpos1, tpos2 - tpos1);
                ++tpos2;
                string tagvalue = tmp.Substring(tpos2, tmp.Length - tpos2);

                // special processing for tags with binary data 
                tpos1 = tagvalue.IndexOf(", use -b option to extract");
                if (tpos1 >= 0)
                    tagvalue.Remove(tpos1, 26);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(taggroup) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagname) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagvalue))
                {
                    lstMetadata.Add(new Metadata
                    {
                        group = taggroup?.Trim(),
                        name = tagname?.Trim(),
                        value = tagvalue?.Trim()
                    });
                }
            }

            // is \r followed by \n ?
            if (epos < output.Length)
                epos += (output[epos + 1] == '\n') ? 2 : 1;
            output = output.Substring(epos, output.Length - epos);
        }
        #endregion ExtractFileMetadataFromString

        return lstMetadata;
    }
```